# issue after update elasticsearch in docker or laradock

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, laradock

I updated ElasticSearch 5.4.1 to 5.6.3 but when I want to run it have some error and don't know how solve it !!!

```
Starting laradock_applications_1 ...
Starting laradock_applications_1 ... done
laradock_workspace_1 is up-to-date
laradock_php-fpm_1 is up-to-date
Recreating laradock_elasticsearch_1 ...
Recreating laradock_elasticsearch_1 ... done
Attaching to laradock_elasticsearch_1
elasticsearch_1        | [2018-02-14T05:45:40,907][WARN ][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [] uncaught exception in thread [main]
elasticsearch_1        | org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: plugin [ingest-geoip] is incompatible with version [5.6.3]; was designed for version [5.4.1]
elasticsearch_1        |        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:136) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
elasticsearch_1        |        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:123) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
elasticsearch_1        |        at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:70) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
elasticsearch_1        |        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:134) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
elasticsearch_1        |        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
elasticsearch_1        |        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:91) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
elasticsearch_1        |        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:84) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
elasticsearch_1        | Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: plugin [ingest-geoip] is incompatible with version [5.6.3]; was designed for version [5.4.1]
elasticsearch_1        |        at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginInfo.readFromProperties(PluginInfo.java:146) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
elasticsearch_1        |        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Spawner.spawnNativePluginControllers(Spawner.java:76) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
elasticsearch_1        |        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:168) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
elasticsearch_1        |        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:342) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
elasticsearch_1        |        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:132) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
elasticsearch_1        |        ... 6 more
laradock_elasticsearch_1 exited with code 1
```

how can I solve it ? :(

Answer (score 0):

```
plugin [ingest-geoip] is incompatible with version [5.6.3]; was designed for version [5.4.1]
```

Look at this message, it's straight forward. I can assume deleting **ingest-geoip plugin** could solve the problem.

[Here is how to do it](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/ingest-geoip.html)

Comment: I tried to remove it !

I used 
docker run -it --rm laradock_elasticsearch bash
and elasticsearch-plugin remove --purge ingest-geoip

Comment: but when exit the bash and again open it , I see that the ingest-geoip doesn't deleted !

Answer (score 0):

In my case, deleting the volume(s) used by the elasticsearch container solved it. Of course, it will delete your data, so you'll have make a backup first.